# How to post to the ticker on facebook, like spotify does with music

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, spotify, ticker

I'm making an app that should post to the ticker on Facebook, of what I'm hearing on my app...
Just like Spotify does with their app..

I've made the Open Graph on facebook, and the FB connection on my app..
I can post news at my wall from my app, but cant really seem to figure out how to do the other, like spotify does it.

Comment: The official term for «live feed» is «ticker».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT: This has now gone public: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/634/**

You will need to wait for the Opengraph beta to go public:

> We are making the Open Graph Beta available to all Facebook
>   developers. This beta gives you access to the docs and tools you need
>   to add Open Graph actions and objects to your app. In addition,
>   Facebook developers are granted access to a pre-release version of
>   Timeline for testing.

Meanwhile, browse through [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/), which are plenty informative. You will be able to post to the [ticker](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/#news-feed) like Spotify does, and create [reports](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/define-units/) on your timeline as well. As a developer, you will be able to see these posts, as well as other developers of your app, but they will not be available to the general public.

You will need to have Facebook [approve the actions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/opengraph-approval/) you propose to use with your app. My advice is to do that sooner than later. No review is being done at the moment as far as I know, but it might help to get your action reviews ahead if you post them now before everyone else does.

Answer (score 0):

Spotify is a Facebook partner.  Since they're a partner they get some extra special privileges that the normal 3rd party developer does not.  You will need to have your company contact facebook to see if you can become a partner.